# Dates appearing one day before the actual date

Tags: lightning-aura-components, date, leads, lightning-datatable, timezone

I am displaying a Lead list using a datatable inside a aura:component. This is the table i am displaying:
[image]
I am developing this app from India. And, when the client opens the same app from USA, this is the table he is getting:
[image]

You can see from the image, when app is opened in the USA, one day is subtracted from the `BirthDate__c` field and this is creating a issue. And, when i pass the date to another aura:component, i am getting the correct date(date displayed in India) in the new aura:component.

This is the code I am using to display the table:

```
<lightning:datatable 
                keyField="id"
                data="{! v.records }"
                columns="{! v.columns }"
                onrowaction="{! c.handleViewDetails }"
                hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>

//controller code
    component.set('v.columns', [
            {label: 'Action', type:'button', typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: 'Name'}, variant:'base'}},
            {label: 'Birth Date', fieldName: 'BirthDate__c', type: 'date', typeAttributes: { month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'}},
            {label: 'Phone Number', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type:'text'}
        ]);
```

And, this is the code i use to send the data to another aura:component

```
handleViewDetails : function(component, event, helper) {
    var row = event.getParam('row');
    var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");

    evt.setParams({
        componentDef: "healthfeed:ResourcesComponent",
        componentAttributes :{name: row.Name,
                              dateOfBirth: row.BirthDate__c}
    });
    evt.fire();
}
```

So, what am i doing wrong here? how can i display same date in India and USA?

Comment: This is the ideal situation, there is a big difference in the time zone of India and USA. The "date" type displays time in the local time zone.

Comment: @rahulgawale yeah. I understand that. My question is, when i pass the date to another aura:component,in this case `ResourcesComponent`,  i am getting the correct date. why is that? if it is a time zone issue, the date shown in `ResourcesComponent`, also should get i day subtracted, right?

Comment: how are you displaying the date in `ResourcesComponent` component?

Comment: `<ui:outputDate value="{!v.dateOfBirth}"/>`

Comment: I fixed it. I added `timeZone="UTC"` to this line: `{label: 'Birth Date', fieldName: 'BirthDate__c', type: 'date', typeAttributes: { month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'}},` inside `typeAttributes`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is due to `ui:outputDate`. I think its showing date in UTC. Also, it is deprecated as of API version 47.0.

Consider using `lightning:formattedDateTime` instead of `ui:outputDate`.

With `lightning:formattedDateTime` you can use the default timezone, which is the runtime environment's time zone. or you can override the default by specifying a specific time zone to the timezone attribute.

```
<lightning:formattedDateTime value="1479944705000" timeZone="UTC" />
```

If you want to show the date in user's time-zone then don't set any value to `timeZone` attribute. If you always want to show date in a specific timezone then you can specify that using `timeZone` attribute.

You can also set the timeZone to the data table column inside `typeAttributes`.

Comment: I added `timeZone="UTC"` to `typeAttributes` and it is fixed. thanks very much.

Comment: Great!! I guess you had already figured it out while I was typing the answer!

Comment: yeah.. i did. anyway, thanks very much for the help.